# Chartjs node-canvas renders low resolution image

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, canvas, chart.js

I am rendering charts using chartjs-node-canvas for chart.js v3 on my backend. Everything works great, however produced images have low resolution. Below attaching 2 versions.

First picture is produced by cahrtjs-node-canvas plugin on nodejs server and second is screenshot from browser. Obviously second image is more clear. Is there a way to improve quality of the rendered image?

[image]

[image]

Comment: second image was given to the browser as SVG, i.e. vector data. first image was given to browser as raster data (a normal picture), but the browser's zoom level is probably not at 100%, so it has to resample the picture. that causes the blurring. -- I'm just here because you tagged `image-processing`. I don't know about these libraries at all.

Comment: Chart.js uses Canvas, it's not SVG. Anyway I got the point, maybe ditortion due to the proportions, also screen DPI may matter.

Comment: What height and width did you specify while creating a new object of ChartJSNodeCanvas? Try setting larger height and width, it might improve the resolution.